# Flashdata not getting saved

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Sorry if the question is repeated, but still I am not able to get the correct answer, and I don't want to use userdata, only flashdata.
I am having issues with my flashdata. When I set it, it is not getting set. Please see below and please help:

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('Lead');
    $leads = $this->Lead->getAllLeads();
    $pageNum = count($leads);
    $this->load->view('main', array('leads' => $leads, 'pageNum' => $pageNum));
}

public function getLeads(){
    $this->load->model('Lead');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $from = $this->input->post('from');
    $to = $this->input->post('to');
    $leads = $this->Lead->getLeads($name, $from, $to);
    $pageNum = count($leads);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('leads', $leads);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('pageNum', $pageNum);
    redirect('main');
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".target" ).change(function(res) {
            var data = $('form').serialize();
            console.log(data);
            $.post('/Leads/getLeads', data, function(res){
                //console.log(res);
            });
        });
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($this->session->flashdata('leads') == TRUE) {
    $leads = $this->session->flashdata('leads');
}
if ($this->session->flashdata('pageNum') == TRUE) {
    $pageNum = $this->session->flashdata('pageNum');
}
?>
    <form method="post" >
        <input class="target" type="text" name="name">
        <input class="target" type="date" name="from">
        <input class="target" type="date" name="to">
        <input class="target" type="hidden" name="pageNumber">
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>LeadsID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Registered Date/Time</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <div id="first">
            <form>
                <?php
                $pagenums = count($leads) / 5 + 1;
                for ($i = 1; $i < $pagenums; $i++){
                    ?>
                        <a href="/Books/getPart/<?= $i ?>"><?= $i; ?></a> |
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        foreach ($leads as $lead) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $lead['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $lead['first_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $lead['last_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $lead['registered_datetime']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $lead['email']; ?></td>
            <?php
        }
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

As you can see, I set the flashdata in Controller and try to access it from View. When I print it, it shows me booleanFALSE.
Thanks a lot!

P.S.: Made some changes, so here I am at the moment. Again, first, when launched, I pass without flashdata, just straight opening 'main' using $this->load->view... Second, opening the main again with new '$leads' and '$pageNum' data. That's all I want. The change is made when requested data changed in form.

Comment: Flash-data only works with redirects

Comment: But in another method, the redirect is not working as well. Please see my edit.

Comment: Why don't you create two simple methods (one to set the flashdata, the other to get it) and see if the problem is in the flashdata or something else?

Comment: Try to change the code as follows : 
$this->session->set_flashdata('pageNum', true);
redirect('/','refresh');

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your session_flash data can you please edit explain on your main post.

Comment: @Rajesh, how to pass data then? If I pass 'pageNum' as true, how will I pass $pageNum? Thanks.

Comment: @wolfgang1983, I am trying to pass it to view, then take it and use it as $leads.

Comment: been a while since I've worked on codeigniter, but is seems to me that when you evaluate your flashdata being true or not, that will clear it out.  So instead of `$leads = $this->session->flashdata('leads');` you should just do `$leads = true;`  same for the other case.  Or set $leads to flashdata, and then evaluate $leads.

Comment: When I redirect, I am redirecting to the same page where I was, to 'main'. Can it be a problem? I am in 'main', now when change made, it goes to 'getLeads()' in Controller, then redirects to 'main'. Can it be a problem? If yes, what can I do about it? Thank you guys.